# Build error on circleci (spin up enviroment )

Tags: yaml, config, circleci

I am facing a problem with the Build error on circle-ci.

this is my [repo](https://github.com/taiga-programming/cinema-app/blob/develop/.circleci/config.yml)

**Error**

```
Build-agent version 1.0.41563-0e4d6629 (2020-10-22T11:30:36+0000)
Docker Engine Version: 18.09.6
Kernel Version: Linux 2e2f534dcc94 4.15.0-1077-aws #81-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 24 16:48:15 UTC 2020 x86_64 Linux
Starting container circleci/node:6.14.8
Warning: No authentication provided, this pull may be subject to Docker Hub download rate limits. 
  image cache not found on this host, downloading circleci/node:6.14.8

Error response from daemon: manifest for circleci/node:6.14.8 not found
```

Answer (score 2):

`6.14.8` is a really historic version. Are you sure you didn't mean `14.6.8`, `14.8.6`, etc.?

In order to see what versions CircleCI supports, see [pre-built CircleCI Docker images](https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/circleci-images/#nodejs).

You can also check official node versions you can pull at https://hub.docker.com/_/node

**Off-topic**: you're not authenticating your pulls. Docker is applying pull rate limit as of Nov 1st, so it would be a good idea to authenticate before the pull, see [Docker auth on CircleCI](https://tekkie.dev/devops/docker/devops-disruption-by-docker-hub-changes#docker-auth-on-circleci) for a tip.